# How to use React Suspense without 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, recoiljs, react-suspense

I'm using **Recoil** but it's resulting in the following warning:

*Warning: Can't perform a React state update on a component that hasn't mounted yet. This indicates that you have a side-effect in your render function that asynchronously later calls tries to update the component. Move this work to useEffect instead*

I can't move the `useRecoilValue` hook into `useEffect` and so instead I'm using React Suspense which then avoids this error on localhost. However the live site doesn't load and eventually results in **504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT**.

Has anyone been able to get `useRecoilValue` working with NextJS?

[image]

selector.js

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { atom, selector } from "recoil";
import client from "../apollo-client";

export const stateQuery = selector({
  key: "siteState",
  get: async ({ get }) => {
    const response = await client.query({
      query: gql`
        {
          siteSettings {
            siteSettings {
              contactEmail
              internationalTelephone
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    });
    return {
      contactEmail: response.data.siteSettings.siteSettings.contactEmail,
      internationalTelephone:
        response.data.siteSettings.siteSettings.internationalTelephone,
    };
  },
});
```

ExampleBlock.js…

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { stateQuery } from "@recoil/selector";
import tw from "twin.macro";

export default function ArticleQuoteBlock({ data: { text, name } }) {
  const { contactEmail, internationalTelephone } = useRecoilValue(stateQuery);

  return (
    <section tw="bg-white quote md:quote-md">
      <div tw="bg-pink quote-inner md:quote-inner-md">
        <h1 tw="quote-text md:quote-text-md">{contactEmail}</h1>
        <h1 tw="quote-text md:quote-text-md">{internationalTelephone}</h1>

        <h1 tw="quote-text md:quote-text-md"></h1>
        {text && (
          <p tw="quote-text md:quote-text-md indent md:indent-md">{text}</p>
        )}
        {name && <p tw="name md:name-md">{name}</p>}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```